# Golang to wasm compilation using tinygo. Execution using wasmtime

Tags: go, webassembly, tinygo, wasmtime

I have the following test code

```
func main() {
    path, err := os.Getwd()
    log.Println(path, err)
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/etc/dse")
    log.Println(files, err)
}
```

I compile it to wasm using

```
tinygo build -target wasi -o list.wasm list.go
```

Then I executeit using

```
wasmtime list.wasm
```

The output is

```
2023/05/05 16:00:50 / <nil>
2023/05/05 16:00:50 [] open /etc/dse: errno 76
```

At the same time, the directory /etc/dse exists and has permissions 777.

What is the source of this error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errno 76` means `capabilities insufficient`.

You have to give it capabilities to access files in the requisite directories, with the `wasmtime` option `--dir` (see [wasmtime WASI tutorial](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime/blob/main/docs/WASI-tutorial.md)):

> The `--dir=` option instructs wasmtime to preopen a directory, and make it available to the program as a capability which can be used to open files inside that directory.

```
$ wasmtime --dir=/etc/dse list.wasm
2023/05/06 01:36:31 / <nil>
2023/05/06 01:36:31 [] readdir unimplemented : errno 54
```

Unfortunately, `readdir` is not implemented in TinyGo yet.

References:

- [TinyGo - Unsupported System Calls](https://wazero.io/languages/tinygo/#unsupported-system-calls)
- [Languages - System Calls](https://wazero.io/languages/#system-calls)
- [stub of ReadDirent in TinyGo](https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo/blob/641a7e5cb9eb41c2bbc1448b49c4f8e5c469dc42/src/syscall/syscall_libc_wasi.go#L226-L228)
- [TinyGo issue - wasi: implement readdir](https://github.com/tinygo-org/tinygo/issues/3087)